# Responsive Menu Error

Tags: html, css

Hello when I go and view my website my mobile view for my menu is still showing. I want it to go back to normal. after 768px;

I have looked every where can find out why its doing it like that.

http://codepen.io/mwbcomputers/pen/jvpcq

Comment: Correct your `max-width: 1024px` to 768px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `display: none;` within your media query for `1024`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
#container {
width: 90%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.nav {  
display: none;
}

// more css
```

Remove the following code from the media query

```
.nav {  
display: none;
}
```